# Add another property when matched with list ID and subList ID in nested array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Initial API has this list

```
const main = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Folder 1',
    list: [
      {
        listId: 3,
        listName: 'List ID 3',
        subList: [
          { id: 1, subListName: 'Sub List ID 1' },
          { id: 2, subListName: 'Sub List ID 2' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Folder 2',
    list: [
      {
        listId: 1,
        listName: 'List ID 1',
        subList: [
          { id: 1, subListName: 'Sub List ID 1' },
          { id: 2, subListName: 'Sub List ID 2' },
        ],
      },
      {
        listId: 2,
        listName: 'List ID 2',
        subList: [{ id: 2, subListName: 'Sub List ID 2' }],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

But I'm creating a different structure that looks like

```
const folders = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Folder 1',
    list: [
      { listId: 3, subListId: 1 },
      { listId: 3, subListId: 2 },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Folder 2',
    list: [
      { listId: 1, subListId: 1 },
      { listId: 2, subListId: 3 },
    ],
  },
]
```

I need to match those ID and add `listName` and `subListName` to those nested object.

Final version how it should look

```
const final = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Folder 1',
    list: [
      { listId: 3, listName: 'List ID 3', subListId: 1, subListName: 'Sub List ID 1' },
      { listId: 3, listName: 'List ID 3', subListId: 2, subListName: 'Sub List ID 2' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Folder 2',
    list: [
      { listId: 1, listName: 'List ID 1', subListId: 1, subListName: 'Sub List ID 1' },
      { listId: 2, listName: 'List ID 2', subListId: 2, subListName: 'Sub List ID 2' },
    ],
  },
]
```

I have tried doing forloops and pushing to new array but i think this is getting messy so looking for a cleaner way

```
const t5 = []

for (const el of folders) {
  const t4 = []

  for (const _el of el.list) {
    let listId
    let subListId

    let listname
    let subListName

    for (const i of main) {
      for (const _i of i.list) {
        if (_i.listId === _el.listId) {
          for (const __i of _i.subList) {
            if (__i.id === _el.subListId) {
              console.log(' ~ __i', _i)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (_el.listId === listId && _el.subListId === 1) {
      t4.push({
        ..._el,
        listname: listname,
        subListName: subListName,
      })
    }
  }

  t5.push({ ...el, list: t4 })
}

console.log(' ~ t5', t5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
const newArray = [];

for (let item of array) {
    const object = {
        id: item.id,
        name: item.name,
        list: []
    }
    for (let list of item.list) {
        object.list.push(...list.subList.map(subList => ({
            listId: list.listId,
            listName: list.listName,
            subListId: subList.id,
            subListName: subList.subListName
        })))
    }
    newArray.push(object);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.reduce` for that.

```js
const main = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Folder 1',
    list: [
      {
        listId: 3,
        listName: 'List ID 3',
        subList: [
          { id: 1, subListName: 'Sub List ID 1' },
          { id: 2, subListName: 'Sub List ID 2' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Folder 2',
    list: [
      {
        listId: 1,
        listName: 'List ID 1',
        subList: [
          { id: 1, subListName: 'Sub List ID 1' },
          { id: 2, subListName: 'Sub List ID 2' },
        ],
      },
      {
        listId: 2,
        listName: 'List ID 2',
        subList: [{ id: 2, subListName: 'Sub List ID 2' }],
      },
    ],
  },
]
const folders = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Folder 1',
    list: [
      { listId: 3, subListId: 1 },
      { listId: 3, subListId: 2 },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Folder 2',
    list: [
      { listId: 1, subListId: 1 },
      { listId: 2, subListId: 2 },
    ],
  },
];

const final = folders.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const node = {
    id: curr.id,
    name: curr.name,
  };
  // Find the node from the main array with id from folders node id
  const mainNode = main.find((item) => item.id === node.id);
  node.list = curr.list.map((listNode) => {
    // From the node found from main array, get the list node
    const listItem = mainNode.list.find((item) => item.listId === listNode.listId);
    // From the list node find the sublist node with id
    const subListItem = listItem ? listItem.subList.find((item) => item.id === listNode.subListId) : null;
    return {
      listId: listItem.listId,
      listName: listItem.listName,
      subListId: subListItem.id,
      subListName: subListItem.subListName,
    }
  });
  acc.push(node);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(final);
```